# Using DataTable.Clone() to save and revert changes to a database

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, strongly-typed-dataset

In order to provide the ability to revert changes that have taken place in a database table, I have created a `Clone()` of the DataTable prior to a large number of changes.  The users have the ability to go through a number of forms before deciding to cancel the changes.  At the end of the process, if they have chosen to cancel, I would like to update the Clone()'d data back to the database.
I'm not sure if it makes sense to delete the row that has already been added and then add back the original Clone()'d row, or to update the row that is scheduled to be updated?
It seems that if I were to update the original row, I would have to loop through to copy the rows from the clone to the original?  Or is there another way?

```
// Clone the original data
cloneDataTable = origDataTable.Clone();
cloneDataTable.ImportRow(dataRow);

// Later in the process, if I need to delete the row
dataRow.Delete();
tableAdapter.Update(dataRow);

// I was considering that I could add the cloned row back in this fashion
origDataTable.ImportRow(cloneDataTable.Rows[0]);
tableAdapter.Update(dataRow);
```

I may have confused the issue but am basically looking for a simple and efficient method of restoring the originally Clone()'d data back to the database after the series of insert/updates have already been performed.
Ideally I would like to perform an update since a database insert causes a sequence value to increment that I'd like to avoid.

Thanks for any help, and please ask for any clarifications if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for implementing an undo/cancel feature like this is to make all the direct changes to the database within the scope of a transaction (assuming your database of choice supports transactions), and then either commit or roll back that transaction based on whether or not your user wishes to make their changes permanent.

Implementing a roll-your-own undo mechanism using a DataTable is not a good plan.

Comment: The design is as it will be.  Each form commits changes throughout a process so I don't have a choice at the point.

Comment: You still have a choice. Even though you write changes to the database at different times and from different forms, you can still make all these changes within the scope of a single transaction (you can't use the `using` block syntax with this as `ElVieejo` suggested, but that's just a minor convenience anyway. The kind of thing you're trying to do is *exactly* what transactions are meant to be used for; I feel the need to re-stress that rolling your own mechanism for this using DataTables is not a good idea. You're throwing away 15 minutes of work (to enable the use of transactions)  ...

Comment: ... so you can spend a great deal more time on getting this DataTable approach to not work very well.

Answer (score 0):

Use transactions, make changes, and complete the transaction if works

```
using(TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope ())
{
//updates, inserts, etc
ts.Complete();
}
```

if an exception or error happen, the transaction will rollback all inside of transactionScope

this if you're using SQL Server
sorry for the bad english!

Comment: The updates occur over a set of forms and classes and posts, etc.  I can't practically wrap it in this sort of structure.

Comment: what about have the dataTAbles in memory, and do the inserts, and updates at the final of usage ? Then you have to use one transaction, and make all the inserts, updates, etc then. 
You ask for an efficient method, and modify the DB, and then modify again to "rollback" is not efficient at all, for many things like creating connections, do each operation twice (do and rollback).. I think that adapte your code to Transaction will be the best option (if its posible)

Answer (score 0):

Due to the complications of the process I had to devise my own solution.  Thank you to those that suggested that creating transactions would work, but it wasn't that straightforward of a solution otherwise I wouldn't have asked.
The issue is that users can choose a point in which to cancel but the state must be tracked and recorded the entire time.  What I ended up doing was when the user requests to save the state, I `Clone()` the DataTable and set a `cloned = true` flag.

Later if a cancel is chosen, I then do a `Merge()` of the old to the new.

```
origDataTable.Merge(cloneDataTable);
tableAdapter.Update(origDataTable.Rows[0]);
```

I hope this helps someone.  It is a bit complex but suits the needs of this application and I like having the ability to maintain my own transactions since I can choose when to save state into memory, write to the database, and revert.
Granted, this may be easier to use some of the built in functionality for transactions in a different design, but it works for this application.
Thanks for the advice.